# wordpress unregister parent theme sidebar in child theme not working

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I see very plainly how the parent theme is registering the widget area (in parent theme's functions.php file):

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'theme_widgets_init' );
function theme_widgets_init(){
    register_sidebar( array (
        'name' => __( 'Sidebar Widget Area', 'text-domain' ),
        'id' => 'primary-widget-area',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => "</li>",
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
```

In simple theory, I don't know why this code (in the child theme folder's functions.php file) is not killing the sidebar widget area from displaying in the backend in Appearance > Widgets:

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'unregister_parent_sidebar' );
function unregister_parent_sidebar(){
    unregister_sidebar( 'primary-widget-area' );
}
```

Comment: You have to lower the prioirty.

The documentation states: "In the example, note that we assign a priority of 11 when registering the widgets_init hook. This is because a child theme's functions.php file is called before the parent theme's, which means that our call to unregister_sidebar() would accomplish nothing since the sidebar has not yet been registered.

By lowering the priority of our action, we ensure that it is called after the parent theme's functions.php file is loaded."

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/unregister_sidebar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give higher weight to un-register sidebars. See 3rd argument in add_action function.

```
    function unregister_widgets_area(){

        // Unregister some of the sidebars
        unregister_sidebar( 'first-widget-area' );
        unregister_sidebar( 'second-widget-area' );
        unregister_sidebar( 'third-widget-area' );
    }

    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'unregister_widgets_area', 11 );
```